# jQuery too much recursion in ajax query

Tags: jquery

I have this part of code which throw a too much recursion error in javasript console, i don't know how to fix it. I'am using too jquery-ui-map :

```
$('#map').gmap({ 'center': '45.76161017250319,6.284972881353269', 'zoom': 12 }).bind('init', function(ev, map) {

});

$('#button').click(function() {
    var list_cities = $('#list_cities').val();
    var building = $('#list_building').val();

    if (building=='-1' && list_cities!='-1') {
        console.log('Please select the building');  
    }else if(list_cities=='-1' && building!='-1'){
       console.log('Please select the city');
    }else if(list_cities=='-1' && building=='-1'){
       console.log('Please select the city and the building');
    }else{
       $.ajax({
           url: 'index.php?option=com_citybuilding&view=distance&format=json',
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "json",
           data: 'city='+list_cities+'&building='+building
      }).done(function(data) {
           $.each(data, function(index, val){ 
               $('#map').gmap('addMarker', { 'position':new google.maps.LatLng(val.lat, val.lng), 'bounds': true, 'icon': 'http://example.com/icon.png' }).click(function() {
                   $('#map').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': '<div><h3>'+val.name+'</h3><img title="'+val.name+'" alt="'+val.name+'" src="http://example.com/media/'+val.image+'" /><br /><h4>Time :</h4> Start : </div>' }, this);                                                        
                });                      

            });
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks by advance

Comment: `else if(list_cities='-1' && building!='-1')` ==> **list_cities='-1'** but I doubt if it will fix the actual bug

Comment: What is the exact error statement?

Comment: What exactly does that first call to `$('#map').gmap()` return? Are you possibly adding that click handler many times to the same elements?

Comment: In javascript console, it display three times the error : too much recursion, first in http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js:37:317, second in http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js:102:1 and the third in http://maps.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/30/3/intl/fr_ALL/map.js:17:327